# Reactjs slide animation problem without unknown target dimensions

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

In my react app I'm doing some kind of animations to make it nicer. I want to make a div appear by sliding from above disappear by sliding it back.

I'm using `bootstrap 5.1.0` and `react-bootstrap 1.6.1` in my stack.

I came up with a solution that is to wrap the content inside a div and toggle its `maxHeight` between `window.innerHeight` and `0` as needed. I added also a custom css class

```
.transition-height{
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Problem is that obviosly, when I close the div, the animation starts from a very hight value of maxHeight and so there's a delay between the close trigger event and the moment when you see the div actually closing. I used `window.innerHeight` as I don't have a known height target value to use, it depends from the length of div content.

I uploaded the code to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-montalcini-26z98?file=/src/App.js), so you can see its behaviour.

**How can I avoid this?**

Comment: Could you just transform down to height 0 with the transition being on the height for the shrinking phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case just need to get the height of the *div* with *useRef* and when will *show = true* set the current height. [codesandbox exapmle](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-napier-kuke3?file=/src/App.js:108-718)

**ApperDiv**

```
const AppearDiv = (props) => {
  let { show = false, className = "", style = {} } = props;
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const getPaperBoxHeight = ref.current?.scrollHeight || 0;

  const filteredProps = Object.entries(props)
    .filter(([k, _]) => !["className", "show", "style"].includes(k))
    .reduce((p, [k, v]) => ({ ...p, [k]: v }), {});

  style = show ? { height: getPaperBoxHeight } : { height: 0 };
  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={
        "overflow-hidden transition-height" + (className && ` ${className}`)
      }
      style={style}
      {...filteredProps}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: scrollHeight is exactly what I needed!